# VMware Converter - from which machine should I run the converter?

Tags: vmware, conversion

i wanna convert a VM *from* and *to* the same host, just for getting unused disk space back.

So my question is how to do it best in terms of speed/time consumption.

Should I run the converter from an external machine, like any win10 machine in the same network?

I saw all it seems to need in LAN bandwidth, there was no CPU or RAM used when i ran the first conversion from a win10 client, just LAN went up to 100%.

so should i maybe even run the converter from another VM on that same host? or whats best?

thanks in advance,

mike

Answer (score 0):

Converter creates a disk file, so you can run it on the machine you wish to convert and keep the file on that machine to use it later. This is easiest.

You can run from another networked machine and point to the machine you wish to convert.

Also, you may consider a cloning app (Acronis or other) to create a copy of the machine to a smaller space and then (assuming you are happy) copy it back to the existing machine.

VMware Converter is a P to V converter so make sure it fits your needs